# What has changed and "My.Settings.CommPort" doesn't work?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, serial-port, my.settings

I'm following a Visual Basic 2013 instructions video to create an ASCOM driver using a template in Visual Studio 2017, but I'm getting an error saying "'CommPort' is not a member of 'MySettings'." Has something changed so that I can't use it as written or is there a setting that I'm missing?

I tried searching for My.Settings.CommPort and the "My.Settings object" language reference page but couldn't find anything.

The part of the code where it is found is the following.

```
If value Then
   ' TODO connect to the device
   Dim comPort As String = My.Settings.CommPort
   objSerial = New ASCOM.Utilities.Serial
   objSerial.Port = 3
   objSerial.Speed = 57600
   objSerial.Connected = True

Else
```

In the video I'm following it builds just fine but I'm getting the error
BC30456 'CommPort' is not a member of 'MySettings'.

Comment: The [`My.Settings`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/objects/my-settings-object) object is used to _store_ and _access_ application settings. The author of the video tutorial you're following must've created an entry in the settings called `CommPort`, that's why they could access it while you can't. Therefore, you need to do the same thing. To add/edit entries in `My.Settings`, open the Project menu and select properties, then head to the 'Settings" tab, type the name of the setting (`CommPort`) and select its type (which should be a string in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, it seems to have fixed it!